# ¿Como puedo hacer un constructor en mi controlador?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

¿Se puede hacer un constructor de mi controlador para instanciar las instancias que debo consumir de los modelos o métodos de mi aplicación?. ¿Como seria?

Ejemplo:

Mi `controller`

```
public class MiControlController : Controller
{
    private MiModelo _MiModelo;

    public MiControl()
    {
        _MiModelo = new MiModelo();
    }

    // Logic
}
```

Comment: cual es el problema que tenes con eso? es core o C# 4.5? en core podes inyectarle los servicios al controller

Comment: No ningún problema, pero quiero reutilizar los servicios para no instanciarlo en cada método de mi controlador, solo hacer un call. Y esto es ASP.NET MVC 5 C#

Comment: Creo que lo que te refieres es esto -> https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members

Comment: No, eso no ya que la instancia que debo instanciar tiene métodos que contienen datos dinámicos por ende no me serviría tenerlos como `static`

Comment: Lo que buscas instanciar es un `DBContext`? caso contrario, estaría bueno que des un ejemplo para poder entender mejor tu problema!

Comment: publique mi respuesta a como lo hice finalmente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente lo solucione de la siguiente forma. (Me gustaría que lo revisaran para ver si realmente esta del todo bien).

```
public class ProfileController : Controller
{
    private MiClase _MiClase;

    public ProfileController()
    {
        _MiClase = new MiClase();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Dato1 = _MiClase.MiMetodoGetDato1();

        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: en mvc 5 tambien tenes inyeccion de dependencias.. mira: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Comment: No veo donde se evita la instanciación

Comment: @gbianchi gracias le echare un vistazo.

Comment: @JDev quizas me explique mal con eso, pero el punto era no escribir la llamada de la instancia n veces en mi controlador del tipo `MiClase _MiClase = new MiClase();`

Comment: Pero eso con tu código inicial tampoco tenias que hacerlo.

Comment: ¿Como? creo que no entendí tu comentario...

Answer (score 0):

Hay varias maneras de hacer lo que me imagino que quieres hacer, que es instanciar un objeto y consumir sus métodos.

## Opción 1: usando el constructor del controlador

```
public class MyOwnController : Controller
{
    private MyClass model;
    public MyOwnController()
    {
        model = new MyClass();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(model.GetInfo());
    }
}
```

## Opción 2: como propiedad

```
public class MyOwnController : Controller
{
    private MyClass model = new MyClass();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(model.GetInfo());
    }
}
```

o

```
public class MyOwnController : Controller
{
    private MyClass model { get { return new MyClass(); } }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(model.GetInfo());
    }
}
```

## Opción 3: métodos de clase

Si vas a ejecutar un método que te devolverá información basada en el contexto, puedes optar por dejar el método como `static` y delegar la tarea:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static string GetInfo(string dato1, int dato2...)
    {
        return ...
    }
}

public class MyOwnController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult UnaVista(string dato1, int dato2)
    {
        return View(MyClass.GetInfo(dato1, dato2));
    }
}
```

De hecho hay más maneras, personalmente te recomendaría usar la opción 3 ya que va más enfocada al concepto de MVC en sí.